# Canvas / Создание эффекта (маски) миража для изображения

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, webgl, svg-animation

Подскажите, есть ли легкий способ создать эффекта [миража(марева)](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/HeatDistortionEffect/) на технологиях canvas / svg для изображения. В приведенном примере используется перемещение текстур, можно ли проще, к примеру для анимации эффекта огня?

Comment: Как бы описание эффекта есть : https://tympanus.net/codrops/2016/05/03/animated-heat-distortion-effects-webgl/

Comment: Это я читал, только не смог толком разобраться. У меня изображение несколько другое и я не смог создать правильную маску перекрытия. Потому-то и ищу решение попроще.

Comment: webgl - я думаю здесь ни кто объяснять не будет - это на самом деле сложное для понимания, это и математика и отличное знание js и написание шейдера это прежде всего взаимодействие на графический процессор ...

Comment: хотя вопрос сам по себе достоин ответа ... подробного ответа ...жаль нету опции Подписаться

Comment: Дайте знать если Вас еще интересует webgl реализация такого эффекта

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выбираем картинку с объемными объектами на дальнем плане, чтобы эффект миража лучше проявился.

*Применение фильтров сильно нагружает видеокарту, поэтому при реальном применении этого эффекта старайтесь уменьшить размеры зоны действия фильтра.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Применяем к ней два фильтра `feTurbulence`и `feDisplacementMap` Подробно о фильтрах, на русском, с многочисленными примерами можно почитать [здесь](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1063/210/lecture/5440?page=5)

За основу создания эффекта миража в фильтре отвечают несколько параметров, но основной параметр это `baseFrequency`

> Частота генерации шума, которая представляется в виде двух чисел,
> определяющих горизонтальное и вертикальное направления. Если задается
> одно число, то оно по умолчанию принимается для обоих направлений.

Вот этот параметр фильтра и будем анимировать с помощью скрипта
Остальные параметры фильтра можете регулировать по своему вкусу.

`scale="6"` - увеличивает размер `волн`

`seed="53"` - отвечает за слоистость структуры

`frames += 0.3` - увеличение прироста фраймов, увеличивает скорость волновых эффектов

```js
var img = document.querySelector("#displacementFilter feTurbulence");
var frames = 0;
var rad = Math.PI / 180;

function AnimateBaseFrequency() {
  //baseFrequency="0.01 .1"
  bfx = 0.01;
  bfy = 0.1;
  frames += 0.8
  bfx += 0.01 * Math.cos(frames * rad);
  bfy += 0.01 * Math.sin(frames * rad);

  bf = bfx.toString() + ' ' + bfy.toString();
  img.setAttributeNS(null, 'baseFrequency', bf);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(AnimateBaseFrequency);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(AnimateBaseFrequency);
```

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 673 455" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
       
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.1 .1"
        numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" seed="53"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="6" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

<image id="blueMoon"  y="90" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke2Ih.png" width="100%" height="100%" />

   <use xlink:href ="#blueMoon"   transform="translate(0, 0) scale(1 1) " filter="url(#displacementFilter)"/>
</svg>   
</div>
```

### Пламя

Чтобы получить тот или иной эффект нужно подобрать несколько однотипных картинок, например горящего огня и после экспериментов с изменением атрибутов фильтров и переменных скрипта пробовать их по очереди, какая картинка будет давать лучший эффект.

```js
 var img = document.querySelector("#displacementFilter feTurbulence");
var frames = 0;
var rad = Math.PI / 180;

function AnimateBaseFrequency() {
  //baseFrequency="0.01 .1"
  bfx = 0.1;
  bfy = 0.1;
  frames += .4
  bfx += 0.05 * Math.cos(frames * rad);
  bfy += 0.1 * Math.sin(frames * rad);

  bf = bfx.toString() + ' ' + bfy.toString();
  img.setAttributeNS(null, 'baseFrequency', bf);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(AnimateBaseFrequency);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(AnimateBaseFrequency);
```

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 670 526" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
       
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01 0.1"
        numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" seed="3"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="10" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

<image id="blueMoon"  y="90" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqhln.jpg"  width="80%" height="100%"  />

   <use xlink:href ="#blueMoon"    filter="url(#displacementFilter)"/>
</svg>   
</div>
```

### Огонь и вода

При обработке изображений необходимо  уменьшить их размеры в любом растровом редакторе. Лучше в фотошопе, у которого есть недокументированная возможность уменьшать поэтапно на 10%  размеры изображения без заметной потери качества. таким образом можно получить из изображения весом `2.2 Mb`  картинку весом `100kb`      В шапке svg файла необходимо выставить размер `viewBox` с атрибутами равными размеру используемой картинки. Например в этом примере - `viewBox="0 0 670 526"`

```js
var img = document.querySelector("#displacementFilter feTurbulence");
var frames = 0;
var rad = Math.PI / 180;

function AnimateBaseFrequency() {
  //baseFrequency="0.01 .1"
  bfx = 0.1;
  bfy = 0.1;
  frames += .31
  bfx += 0.1 * Math.cos(frames * rad);
  bfy += 0.1 * Math.sin(frames * rad);

  bf = bfx.toString() + ' ' + bfy.toString();
  img.setAttributeNS(null, 'baseFrequency', bf);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(AnimateBaseFrequency);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(AnimateBaseFrequency);
```

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 680 409" preserveAspectRatio="none" >  
       
 <filter id="displacementFilter">
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.1 .1"
        numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" seed="53"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

<image id="blueMoon"  y="90" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ptDK.png" width="100%" height="100%" />

   <use xlink:href ="#blueMoon"     filter="url(#displacementFilter)"/>
</svg>   
</div>
```

### Update

Во всех примерах используется `requestAnimationFrame`

Поддержка браузерами на 21.11.2021

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Применение фильтров сильно нагружает видеокарту, поэтому при реальном применении этого эффекта старайтесь уменьшить размеры зоны действия фильтра.

Comment: я лично хотел бы увидеть ответ по WebGL так как эта технология мощнее

Comment: Хороший ответ и ссылка замечательная! Вот почитай https://html5.by/blog/what-is-requestanimationframe/ как уменьшить количество обновлений для requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Да и кстати - ноут у меня так себе но если я открою пример с SVG  у себя на весь экран то начинает шуметь куллер а вот если пример с tympanus то куллер молчит - что говорит об оптимизации процессора в коде WebGL  что как раз не возможно сделать в SVG

Answer (score 2):

Вот смастерил **WebGL** версию такого фильтра, за основу взят код вот из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949125/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-radial-blur-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-svg/951405#951405) поста, там я уже делал фильтр для текстуры.

Алгоритм:

```
  // запоминаем текущую текстурную координату
vec2 p_d = uv; 
  // прибавляем dt (сколько прошло времени с прошлого кадра)
p_d.y += t * 0.1; 
  // берем для полученного значения текстурных координат сэмпл 2d шума 
  // (тут могла быть текстура вместо вызова математического метода, и это будет быстрее)
vec2 offset = vec2(noise(p_d * 22.));     
  // плавно уменьшаем это значения до 0 (0 сверху)
offset *= uv.y * 0.01; 
  // берем цвет оригинальным координатам + смещение
return sample(uv.xy + offset);
```

```js
let t = new Date().getTime();
let url = "https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/images/computer-history-museum/pos-z.jpg";

let filter = webglFilter(url, `

  uniform float t;

  float rand(vec2 n) { 
    return fract(sin(dot(n, vec2(12.9898, 4.1414))) * 43758.5453);
  }

  float noise(vec2 p){
    vec2 ip = floor(p);
    vec2 u = fract(p);
    u = u*u*(3.0-2.0*u);

    float res = mix(
      mix(rand(ip),rand(ip+vec2(1.0,0.0)),u.x),
      mix(rand(ip+vec2(0.0,1.0)),rand(ip+vec2(1.0,1.0)),u.x),u.y);
    return res*res;
  }
  
  vec4 frag (vec2 uv) {
    vec2 p_d = uv;
    p_d.y += t * 0.1;
    vec2 offset = vec2(noise(p_d*22.));
    offset *= uv.y * 0.01; 
    return sample(uv.xy + offset);
  }
`);

filter.ready = function() { 
  let c = filter.canvas;
  document.body.append(c);
  animate();
}

function animate() {
  filter.uniform('1f', 't', (new Date().getTime() - t)/1000)
        .apply();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<script>
function webglFilter(url, fragCode) {
  
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let pid, gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') 
        || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  
  let loader = new Image();
  loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  loader.src = url;
  loader.onload = function() { 
    
    canvas.width = loader.width;
    canvas.height = loader.height;

    pid = gl.createProgram();

    shader(`
      attribute vec2 coords;
        void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
      }
    `, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

    shader(`
      precision highp float;
      uniform sampler2D texture;

      vec4 sample(vec2 uv) {
          return texture2D(texture, uv);
      }

      ${fragCode}

      void main(void) {
          gl_FragColor = frag(vec2( 
            gl_FragCoord.x / ${canvas.width}.,  
            1. - gl_FragCoord.y / ${canvas.height}. 
          ));
      }
    `, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.linkProgram(pid);
    gl.useProgram(pid);

    let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, loader);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

    var textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, "texture");
    gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, 0);
 
    filter.ready && filter.ready();
    filter.apply();
    
    function shader(src, type) {
      let sid = gl.createShader(type);
      gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
      gl.compileShader(sid);
      var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
      gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
      if (message.length > 0) {
        console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
          return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
        }).join('\n'));
        throw message;
      }
    }
  }
  
  let filter = {
    
    canvas: canvas,
    
    ready: null,
    
    uniform: function(type, name, v1, v2, v3, v4) {
      if (!pid)
        throw new Error('program not ready');
      var ul = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, name);
      gl['uniform' + type](ul, v1, v2, v3, v4);
      return filter;
    },
    
    apply: function() {
      if (!pid)
        throw new Error('program not ready');
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
      gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
      return filter;
    }
  }
  
  return filter;
}
</script>
<style>
body{
margin:0;

}
</style>
```

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский по Вашим просьбам сделал вот