# Пробую написать игру на JS canvas и столкнулся с проблемой

Tags: javascript, canvas

Вот игровой цикл. Проблема в функции update. Почему то переменна dt (разница времени настоящего и времени последнего обновления) при присвоении через +=, дает undefined! Что делать ребят:с?

```
 //#############################################################
//#Описание игрового цикла
//#############################################################
var lastTime;

function gameLoop(){
var now = Date.now();
var dt = (now - lastTime);

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);
    drawMap();


    update(dt);// И проблема в этой функции, выглядит она так ->
//function update(dt) {
//player.posX +=Math.floor(player.speedX*dt);
//И в итоге player.posX - undefined, хотя до этого имел значение 50
//
//}





    processKey();//обрабатывает нажатие клавиш например ->
// if(isKeyDown("D")){
//        player.speedX= 200;
//        player.move = true;
//
//
//
//    }




    drawImage(player.sprite,player.posX,player.posY,player.move);
    lastTime = now;
requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
//#############################################################
```

Comment: не может быть :( Сделайте пример.

Comment: да, выглядит приемлемо

Comment: Вы дебажили переменную `dt` через консоль?  Вставьте сразу перед вызовом ф-ии `update` вывод в консоль значения переменной `dt`, и в самом начале внутри ф-ии `update`, где-нибудь будет выводиться `undefined` вместо числа?  (Чтобы было понятно какая строка в консоли откуда, можно указать флаги, например `console.log("in update dt = ", dt)`)

Comment: И ещё, при первом заходе в ф-ию `gameLoop`, какое значение имеет переменная `lastTime`?  Я не увидел, чтобы переменной `lastTime` присваивалось какое-то значение в коде (см. пример Stranger in the Q), может, она и даёт `undefined`?  (Но возможно Вы просто в примере кода упустили это присваивание)

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно исползую вот такой способ:

```
let t = new Date().getTime();
... 
animate();

function animate() {
  let dt = new Date().getTime() - t;
  ...
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/927012/188366) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/959566/188366) я постил рабочие примеры