# Есть ли способ использовать SVG-градиент в качестве входных данных для фильтра feDisplacementMap?

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation, svg-filter

Я пытаюсь сгенерировать градиент, который я мог бы использовать в качестве входных данных для фильтра `feDisplacementMap` для искажения текста в SVG. Как мне это реализовать?

Я пытался создать его, как часть SVG и скрыть градиент, но не могу заставить его работать таким образом.

```html
<svg
          filter="url(#f)"
          overflow="auto"
          viewBox="0,0,200vw,200vh"
          width="100%"
          height="100vh"
        >
          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="rg" r=".9">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    
            <filter id="f" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
              <feImage result="pict2" xlink:href="#witness"></feImage>
              <feDisplacementMap
                scale=".05"
                xChannelSelector="R"
                yChannelSelector="R"
                in2="pict2"
                in="SourceGraphic"
              ></feDisplacementMap>
            </filter>
    
            <pattern id="imageFill" width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
              <image id="ripples" width="300" height="300" xlink:href="" />
            </pattern>
          </defs>
          <text height="100vh" text-anchor="middle" class="svgText">
            <tspan height="100vh" x="50%" y="50%">text</tspan>
          </text>
          <rect
            id="witness"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            stroke="none"
            opacity="0"
            fill="url(#rg)"
          />
        </svg>
```

Я хотел бы иметь возможность искажать текст сгенерированным градиентом, сохраняя его скрытым.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Is there a way to use a SVG gradient as input to a displacement map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57994390/7394871) от участника  [@rui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12085451/rui).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57994390/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы фильтр работал, вам нужно использовать данные URI для `feImage`.
Я использую ваш градиент, но фильтр, который вы используете, имеет небольшой размер.
Я применяю -   `scale = "15"`

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
<defs>
<filter id="f" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300">
      <feImage xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg width='300' height='300' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E %3CradialGradient id='rg' r='.7'%3E %3Cstop offset='0%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='10%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='20%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='30%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='40%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='50%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='60%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='70%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='80%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='90%25' stop-color='%23000'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='100%25' stop-color='%23f00'%3E%3C/stop%3E% %3C/radialGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Crect fill='url(%23rg)' width='300' height='300'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/svg%3E" result="pict2"/>
      <feDisplacementMap scale="15" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="R" in2="pict2" in="SourceGraphic"/>
   </filter> 
</defs>
  
   <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" height="300" width="300" filter="url(#f)" />
</svg>
```

Также в вашем коде есть несколько ошибок:

1. `viewBox` аттрибут не может иметь наименование данных. Это не будет работать: <del>viewBox="0,0,200vw,200vh"</del>
2. Также вы не можете написать: <del><text height="100vh"</del> или: <del><tspan height="100vh"</del>,
   однако вы можете указать размер шрифта для вашего текста.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57996370/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

- Применяем радиальный градиент :

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#txt1 {
font-size: 200px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
fill:url(#rg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 750 300"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                   
    <defs>
      <radialGradient id="rg" r=".9">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    </defs>
    <text id="txt1" x="15%" y="75%"  >Stack</text>
  </svg>
  </div>
```

- Добавляем фильтры: `feTurbulence` и `feDisplacementMap`

Изменяя значения атрибутов фильтра `feTurbulence` -  baseFrequency и `scale` фильтра -`feDisplacementMap` , вы можете получить интересные эффекты

Анимация стартует когда вы наводите курсор на текст: `begin ="txt1.mouseover"`
и заканчивается, когда уводите курсор: `end ="txt1.mouseout"` или по истечению времени - `dur ="18s"`

Ниже пример анимации искажения текста:

```css
.container {
background-color:blue;
}
#txt1 {
font-size: 200px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
fill:url(#rg);
filter:url(#myFilter);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  width="750" height="300" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 750 300"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                   
    <defs>
       <radialGradient id="rg" r=".9">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
       <filter id="myFilter" >
         <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0001" numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" >
          <animate attributeName="baseFrequency"
            dur="18s"
            values="0.0001;0.02;0.0001;0.02;0.0001"
            begin="txt1.mouseover"
            end="txt1.mouseout" />
      </feTurbulence>
     <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter>
    </defs>
    <text id="txt1" x="1%" y="50%"  >Stack</text>

</div>
```

- Пример анимации искажения картинки и текста:

*Наведите курсор на изображение*

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;
}

#txt1 {
font-size: 100px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
fill:url(#rg);
filter:url(#myFilter);
pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"   viewBox="0 0 500 300">
  <defs> 
  <radialGradient id="rg" r=".9">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
              <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f00"></stop>
            </radialGradient>
    <filter id="myFilter" >
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0001" numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" >
     <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="18s" values="0.0001;0.02;0.0001;0.02;0.0001" begin="img1.mouseover" end="img1.mouseout" />
      </feTurbulence>
     <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHGO8.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#myFilter)" /> 
   <text id="txt1" x="35%" y="35%"  >Stack</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Связанный вопрос: [Canvas / Создание эффекта (маски) миража для изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/941702/28748)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58001164/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>